# titling.sty error in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

I am getting a very annoying error when I try to run rmarkdown docs knitting to pdf from mac

```
output file: Untitled2.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: File `titling.sty' not found.
```

Does anyone know a simple solution? I think what caused it was trying to re-install MacTex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a discussion about this problem [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/359).

It probably means your TeX installation is incomplete. I had the same problem on Ubuntu because I installed `texlive` instead of `texlive-full`.

Comment: Theres an small error in your link, you added "here" to the address.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems: 1) have you used `\usepackage {titling}` in your front matter? 2) after you reinstalled MacTex, did you install titling into your tex library?

Answer (score 1):

The package in question is meant for typesetting in titling. Read about it on the archives here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling.

You can install it through the MacOS utility that TeXlive provides in /Applications/TeX (http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/). Hope this helps.